# How to read and send SMS the same way Cerberus manages

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to make an application that will "hijack" incoming messages that contain a keyword and a command and then respond accordingly, the same way Cerberus SMS commands work. How should I go about making this? I've read that only the default SMS application can alter/delete/silence SMS. How did Cerberus manage it and how can I?

Comment: "I've read that only the default SMS application can alter/delete/silence SMS." – Since KitKat (4.4), yeah, that's basically the case. Before that, it was sometimes possible to abort the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast in a high priority Receiver before other apps could get it. "How did Cerberus manage and how can I?" – Before KitKat, just as I described. Since then, it looks like Cerberus is not using text SMS anymore. Quoting [their help page](https://www.cerberusapp.com/help/en): "If your device has Android 4.4 or a later version, send SMS commands to it from Client Cerberus, so they are hidden"

Comment: If they are still using SMS, then it would be data SMS, as those are not handled by the default app, nor are they ultimately saved to the SMS Provider.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just remembered I have Android 4.01, so that's why SMS works normally in my phone for Cerberus.